# MySQL: JOIN tables and return a column from a row depending on an aggregate function on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let there be two tables:

- Table A

  ```
  id | name
  1    x
  2    y
  ```
- Table B

  ```
  foreign_key | value | external
  1             1       60
  1             2       50
  2             3       80
  2             4       90
  ```

The desired result is a `JOIN` looking like this:

```
id | name | external
1    x      50
2    y      90
```

i.e., for each row in `A` we get the corresponding `external` from `B` where `value` is max for a given `id`.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT
    A.`id`,
    A.`name`,
    B.`external`
FROM `A`
LEFT JOIN `B`
ON A.id = B.foreign_key
GROUP BY id
```

This obviously returns the first `B.external` encountered instead of the one with the highest `value`:

```
id | name | external
1    x      60
2    y      80
```

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably without using subqueries?

Comment: If you really don't want to use a subquery, then you can use a LEFT JOIN as described in the manual (see the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), but it will be significantly slower than the uncorrelated query used as the accepted answer in the 'duplicate' link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why dont want sub-query but Correlated sub-query looks simpler to me

```
select id, name,
      (Select external 
       from TableB B where A.id = B.foreign_key Order by Value desc Limit 1 ) 
From TableA A
```

If you want to achieve this using `JOIN` then you may have to join the `TableB` twice